# MongoDB Driver Fields Exclude

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-csharp

Meu problema é o seguinte, tenho um objeto:

```
public class Obj(){
    prop int id {get; set;}
    prop Client client {get; set;}
}

public class Client(){
   prop int id {get; set;}
   prop Group group {get; set;}
}

public class Group(){
   prop int id {get; set;}
}
```

Ao efetuar a query, gostaria de retornar apenas alguns valores do objeto:

```
var lRetorno = collection.Find(Query.And(query))
                .SetFields(Fields<Obj>.Include(c => c.id, c => c.Client)
                .Exclude(c => c.Client.Group))
```

Existe uma forma de retornaar o obj `Client` sem o mapeamento do objeto `Group`, sem alterar o mapeamento da classe, inclusive?

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço diretamente C#, mas o que você precisa verificar é o suporte para projeções do seu driver.

No [quick tour](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/getting_started/quick_tour/) da documentação do driver c# do mongo existe uma seção sobre projeção, que menciona um [Builder](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/driver/definitions/#projections) de projeções. Esses dois lugares devem te ajudar.

Comment: Já li toda a documentação. Se você mesmo observar, nenhum dos exemplos mostra as ações em segundo nível de objeto. E é exatamente o meu problema, após o primeiro nível. Não ocorre nenhuma falha no exemplo do post, simplesmente não funciona. Retorna tudo e. =T

Comment: Entendi. Achei essa [pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803373/is-it-possible-retrieve-only-one-specific-field-of-a-subdocument-from-an-array) no stackoverflow (em inglês) que a resposta comenta que as projeções são feitas no cliente (com LINQ). Você está usando isso? Como você não tem listas nesses teus objetos quem sabe vale considerar que não seja tão custoso buscar o teu objeto com todas as dependências, isso é um documento só no banco?

Comment: As consultas são feitas com lambda, e são consultas bem consideráveis. No exemplo do post só usei objeto agregado mas na aplicação existem muitos níveis de objetos e listas agregadas. Já imaginou o consumo sem necessidade disso? =T